# Should I reframe and post this question on Law SE instead of ELU?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

Should I reframe and post this question on Law SE instead of ELU?

https://english.stackexchange.com/q/365054/112436

Answer (score 2):

*Should?*  Sounds like it could be on-topic, but I don't know any way to determine how valuable a question it is until it's actually posted for voting.

*Amendment:* I'd recommend reframing and posting to Law.SE something along the lines of, "Do italics have special meaning in legal documents?" or, "What style guides or rules, if any, apply to legal filings in U.S. venues?"  [The answer on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/365060/67775) seems to have addressed the particular style guide you found.  If there *is* an answer to the *Why?* question I imagine it's more likely to be known by legal experts, hence more on-topic here.

Comment: I.e. is it likely I will get more useful answers here than I got there?  If I repost here, what reframing, if any, should I make?  Guidance with those familiar with SE Law would be much appreciated.  This is an "Is such-and-so question appropriate on this site" question.

Comment: @aparente001 - got it; just amended my answer.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm not sure about the editing/framing.  The question as I wrote it really captures what I want to know (both why, to get the intuition, and also what do I do about non-legal uses of "see" in the same document).  May I post the question as is, and then would you be game to propose edits that you feel might be necessary?  I'm asking because I believe SE frowns on cross-posting of questions.  Maybe I should simply delete the old one?  I would have liked to try putting a bounty on it.  But I need the answer by Tuesday, so I don't have time for a very step by step approach.

Comment: @aparente001 I don't think that will work.  What you're asking for there is essentially assistance in drafting a legal document.  That would be closed here as a "request for legal advice."

Comment: No, no, I was only asking which text to italicize.  I included some sample verbiage so people could get an idea what it looks like.  I think I understand why you reacted that way -- Law SE must get a lot of people trying to get *legal guidance*.  But that question about italics is not one of those questions.

Comment: I'm currently thinking that since my case is going to be divided up into two documents, one for the petition (i.e. the appeal) and one for the "memorandum of law," I could use plain text (non-italics) in the petition and italics in the memorandum, and that way I would have to struggle to decide when to italicize "see" and when not to. That is, I could make myself a rule: in the petition, don't italicize "see," and in the memorandum, always italicize "see", "also see". (The reason I will submit two documents, instead of putting everything into one document is that they allow 20 pages for each.)